# CMD Find Network Usage

Tags: shell, networking, command-line, cmd

My work computer is using an insane amount of data every month. It is driving my ISP costs through the roof.

Is there a way in command line to list all the "Devices/Objects" on the network to see what is using all my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor your network traffic using: netstat -e
Please read this article : 
https://www.petri.com/netstat-command-monitor-network-traffic

Also why don't you try to use Resource Monitor- it is available in all windows Machines.[image]

It will tell you how much data is used by what app.

Comment: Almost exactly what I needed! +1 One last thing, you might want to include the link speed command `wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed` source: https://superuser.com/questions/412952/how-to-detect-the-speed-fast-or-gigabit-ethernet-of-a-network-connection-over